# tcpdump filename with -C and -W option

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I am trying to capture tcpdump in Linux and I used the `-C` and `-W` option to enable capturing tcpdump with file size limited to 250MB.

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -s0 -vvv -W 999 -C 250 -w FILENAME.pcap. -Z root
```

On the other hand, the output I am getting is

```
FILENAME.pcap.001
FILENAME.pcap.002
FILENAME.pcap.003
```

But I would like to know how to make the output file name into:

```
FILENAME001.pcap
FILENAME002.pcap
FILENAME003.pcap
```

Thanks for any help you can suggest!

Comment: tcpdump doesn't have that feature. Either you post process the file names with your own script or you modify the tcpdump source code to add in that feature.

Comment: @kaylum, thank you for the response. Can you suggest way to rename tcpdump with -C option output at runtime, I mean while the tcpdump is still running and the file is already created, in a bash script. Or should I really run a separate script for that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcpdump has no such function built in. You can run something like this in the end to rename your files though:

```
for f in FILENAME.pcap.*; do
    mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/FILENAME.pcap.\(.*\)/FILENAME\1.pcap/')";
done
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use -z feature which stands that :

-z postrotate-command
              Used  in  conjunction  with the -C or -G options, this will make tcpdump run " postrotate-command file " where file is the savefile being
              closed after each rotation. For example, specifying -z gzip or -z bzip2 will compress each savefile using gzip or bzip2.

```
          Note that tcpdump will run the command in parallel to the capture, using the lowest priority so that this  doesn't  disturb  the  capture
          process.

          And in case you would like to use a command that itself takes flags or different arguments, you can always write a shell script that will
          take the savefile name as the only argument, make the flags & arguments arrangements and execute the command that you want.
```